# Elixir : Correct way to start child using Dynamic Supervisor

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor, gen-server

I am trying to create a dynamic supervisor to start child processes. There are three modules I am using to do this, one is the main module, the second one is the Dynamic Supervisor and the third is the genserver. I do not get any errors but I am not able to see any child processes running.

Here is my code. The first one is the module having the main method

```
defmodule Simulator do
    def main(args) do
        {:ok, super_pid} = PersonManager.start_link(args)
        num_of_persons = 1
        start_persons(num_of_persons)
        IO.inspect PersonManager.count_children, label: "The Persons started in main method are"
    end

    def start_persons(num_of_persons) when num_of_persons >=1 do
        PersonManager.add_node(private_key, public_key, 0)
        start_persons(num_of_persons-1)    
    end
    # num_of_persons == 0 case handled
end
```

The following is a dynamic Supervisor

```
defmodule PersonManager do
  use DynamicSupervisor

  def start_link(args) do
    DynamicSupervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def add_node(private_key, public_key, num_of_coins) do
    # The code flow does come here, used inspect to check
    child_spec = {Person, {private_key, public_key, num_of_coins}}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, child_spec)
    #The code flow does come here, used inpect to check.   
  end
end
```

The following is the GenServers the worker is supposed to create

```
defmodule Person do
  use GenServer

  def init({private_key, public_key, address, num_of_coins}) do
    IO.puts "Starting a person"
    {:ok, %{private_key: private_key, public_key: public_key, num_of_coins: num_of_coins}}
  end

  def start_link({private_key, public_key, address, num_of_coins}) do
    IO.puts "Starting a person"
    GenServer.start_link(
      __MODULE__,
      {private_key, public_key, address, num_of_coins}
      name: {:global, "node:#{public_key}"},
    )
  end
end
```

I expect the genserver to be running but I get `The Persons started in main method are: %{active: 0, specs: 0, supervisors: 0, workers: 0}`

I dont know why the supervisor is not able to start the genserver. 
Any help would be good.
TIA

Comment: `num_of_persons` is not defined in `start_persons(num_of_persons)` in the `Simulator.main/1`. Please post the real code or provide a correct MCVE.

Comment: My bad, Thanks for pointing that out. I was trying to explain in minimal terms. Here is my full code https://pastebin.com/2z33qhsX. Also this is one of helper modules https://pastebin.com/aZwmD9ig

Comment: I will check it a bit later if there won’t be an answer yet. Maybe try to `Process.sleep(1_000)` before checking the children? It’s not a direct child, the call is asynchronous, so there is no guarantee it will arise immediately.

Comment: Yeah Sure, i couldnt find any children even after putting the process to sleep.

Comment: Check https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#module-child_spec-1 for the correct way to construct a child spec in the `DynamicSupervisor`; specifically, you'll need to do `{Person, [private_key, public_key, num_of_counts]}` and make sure the `Person.start_link` function can handle all those arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Yawar, that did it. My start_link had 4 arguments and i was calling with 3. I didnt know how to handle the output of start_link and check whether the genserver started or not. I would prepare a solution which checks that so that other people stumbling across such problems know how to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case you'll need to do three things:

Set up the child spec correctly before starting it from the `DynamicSupervisor`:

```
child_spec = {Person, [private_key, public_key, num_of_coins]}
```

Force the child start to fail if it's not successful:

```
case DynamicSupervisor.start_child do
  {:ok, _pid} -> {}
  {:error, {:already_started, _pid}} -> {}
  error -> raise error
end
```

And, ensure that the child process can handle the exact arguments the supervisor gives it:

```
defmodule Person do
  use GenServer

  def start_link([], private_key, public_key, num_of_coins) do
    GenServer.start_link(
      __MODULE__,
      {private_key, public_key, num_of_coins},
      name: {:global, "node:#{public_key}"}
    )
  end

  def init({private_key, public_key, num_of_coins}) do
    {:ok, %{private_key: private_key, public_key: public_key, num_of_coins: num_of_coins}}
  end
end
```

Comment: actually, signature of start_link in this situation should look like this: `def start_link([private_key, public_key, num_of_coins]) `